# Kubernetes Pod Logs stream in browser using springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

Hi I want to stream Kubernetes pod logs to Browser UI. is it possible? any sample code can we get?.

My API is running in Spring Boot application, when someone calls my API, have to push (stream) pod logs to client via API. How to do?

Comment: For that you push your logs to cloud watch and from their you should consume.

Comment: We have own Prod App portal where we wanted to stream. That's the reason wanted to check if its possible and how can to do that?

Comment: Either you should use any centralized storage or service to insert or retrieve the logs. That is the option, you cannot directly access the K8s pod logs if your app is running outside.

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1**

Write the app code which will request to the API server in Kubernetes like **Kubernetes Dashboard** to get the **logs**.

You can use the **sprint-boot** or another client **K8s** library as per requirement.

```
func main() {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    namespace := "default"
    podName := "test-pod"

    podLogOpts := &kubernetes.PodLogOptions{
        Container: "test-container",
    }
    req := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).GetLogs(podName, podLogOpts)
    podLogs, err := req.Stream(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer podLogs.Close()

    // Print the logs
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := podLogs.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Print(string(buf[:n]))
    }
}
```

Not a scalable option if you have users in a ton.

**Option 2**

**If you are looking for saving the Logs, and keep it for few days**

You can use the **Fluentd** or some short or **log collector** (Graylog is also there) and push the logs to **Elasticsearch** database.

Write the code in your preferable lang to fetch the data from **elasticsearch** with the **Query & Search** option you are looking for.

**Go Lang** (Just noticed you mentioned Sprint-boot but sorry you can get idea at least not Java guy)

```
func main() {
    // Create a connection to ES
    client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http://localhost:9200"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to Elasticsearch: %v", err)
    }

    // Search to fetch logs
    searchService := client.Search().Index("logs").Type("log")
    searchService.Sort("@timestamp", false)
    searchService.Size(10)

    // Search and get the results
    result, err := searchService.Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to search: %v", err)
    }

    // Results
    for _, hit := range result.Hits.Hits {
        log.Printf("Log: %s", hit.Source)
    }
}
```

You can use **WebSocket** to stream the logs **Browser** so they get real-time quick logs.

**JS**

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/logs");

socket.onmessage = function(event)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i would prefer to use k8 java lib and do you have any sample code?

Comment: no sorry dont have the example for java lib but based on this you will get the idea how to use it with java